# Add Install from Web tab in the Extension manager gives console error

Tags: joomla-3.x

Add Install from Web tab in the Extension manager gives console error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

When clicking on "Add Install from Web tab" button getting a console error
http://prntscr.com/jhzff2

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what exact version of Joomla you're using, but this sounds like a bug and should be reported on the [Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues)